# Stop Emacs font-lock from reducing the font size of symbols in Lisp modes

Tags: emacs, clojure, font-lock

When font-lock colourises my Lisp buffers (in `clojure-mode` and `emacs-list-mode`, at least, so I'm assuming all Lisp modes are affected as well), the font size of my symbols is getting reduced. In this case, I think a picture **is** worth a thousand words:

[image]

As you can see, this leads to the indentation looking wrong, due to the symbols `arena-ended-games-limit` and `game-status` appearing in a smaller font than the other text in the buffer.

Does anyone know where this is being configured, and how I can turn it off?

I've Googled and read through lots of Emacs Lisp files to no avail, but as I don't really know what I'm looking for, I may have overlooked an obvious answer.

In case it matters, here is the ELPA package prologue from my `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; packages
(defvar my-packages '(starter-kit
                      starter-kit-lisp
                      starter-kit-bindings
                      auto-complete
                      rainbow-delimiters
                      clojure-mode
                      cider
                      magit)
  "A list of packages to ensure are installed at launch.")

(dolist (p my-packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (package-install p)))
```

I'm fairly certain that nothing in [starter-kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) / starter-kit-lisp is doing this, as I've read through the source pretty closely, but one never knows.

Comment: If you type `M-x describe-face` and just hit `RET`, it will show you the face used for the text under point.  You could use that to compare the faces used for symbols and for other text.  I suspect one of those faces has a setting for font size.

Comment: The faces, in turn, will probably be set in whatever color theme you're using.  After you `describe-face` as @legoscia suggested, you can look for the offending lines in the theme setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [legoscia's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931732/stop-emacs-font-lock-from-reducing-the-font-size-of-symbols-in-lisp-modes?noredirect=1#comment40595793_25931732), I've been able to figure out that the face that is responsible is `font-lock-function-name-face`, which sets the font family to Verdana, and the height to 0.9. Once I'd figured this out, I used the customise utility to remove the face and height changes, which resulted in the following being added to my `init.el`:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "LightSkyBlue" :weight bold)))))
```

Now everything lines up nicely!